# How to create layout with buttons sliding in from the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I want to create a main menu screen layout. The layout basically has a linear layout which is 40 dp from the left, also there are four buttons in another linear layout.

Now, what I want to achieve is that when the user reaches the main menu screen, the four button should swipe in from the bottom , I know I need to inflate the first layout with the  layout holding the button, I have studied a bit about interpolators on developer android, but I am still not able to achieve what I want.

Can any one help me as how I can achieve this, an example or a tutorial on inflation would help, but inflation must be from bottom to top or top to bottom.

Comment: It might help to show the code you have already tried to implement, so that we have something to work off of. It's unlikely that someone will write an entire activity for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correct you just need to animate your buttons(sliding from bottom to top). The first you need to define your animation in your R.anim smth like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-200%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="200%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="3000"/>

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="3000" />
</set>
```

Then you need to apply animation to your view or layout:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
a.reset();
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);
tv.clearAnimation();
tv.startAnimation(a);
```